# how to replace `links` with `depends_on` in a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

The [docker compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) specifies that `links` is deprecated and should be replaced with `depends_on`. I can't figure exactly how.

Here is the working docker-compose file (with `links` instructions) of an application which has 3 services:

- a nginx reverse proxy
- a nodejs app
- a php api

---

```
version: "3.1"

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./php/content:/srv/www/content
      - ./static:/srv/www/static
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php:php-app
      - nodejs:nodejs-app

  nodejs:
    image: node:alpine
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    working_dir: /home/app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs:/home/app
    links:
      - php:php-app
    command: ["node", "index"]

  php:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html
```

---

The related nginx `default.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /srv/www;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @nodejs;  
  }

  location /api {
    rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ break;
    proxy_pass http://php-app:80;
  }

  location @nodejs {
    proxy_pass http://nodejs-app:8080;
  }
}
```

---

The `links` instructions make aliases from the docker service names to the `proxy_pass`  names in the nginx conf.

How is it possible to replace the `links` instructions in the docker-compose file with `depends_on` without modifying the nginx config (and keep the aliases)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The docker compose documentation specifies that `links` is deprecated and should be replaced with `depends_on`.

It does not. The docs only say, that

> `links` also express dependency between services in the same way as `depends_on`, so they determine the order of service startup.

I fail to see how this concludes, that you should use `depends_on` instead of `links`. Instead, it says, that if you need to run something in a container from the other container, you should use `depends_on`, not `links`. (For example, you `command`-specify running migrations in `php` container and need to wait for `postgres` container).

On the other hand, `links` has a warning saying

> Unless you absolutely need to continue using it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate communication between two containers instead of using `--link`.

In this context, `--link` for `docker` cli is the same thing as `links` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Now, to the point, if you have your containers on one network, you do not need any further special specification. Unless you specify otherwise, the default network driver is `bridge`. So, if you specify your `docker-compose.yml` as following, you should have all your container on one network and aware of each other automatically.

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./php/content:/srv/www/content
      - ./static:/srv/www/static
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  nodejs:
    image: node:alpine
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    working_dir: /home/app
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./nodejs:/home/app
    command: ["node", "index"]
  php:
    image: php:apache
    volumes:
      - ./php:/var/www/html
```

In this case `nginx` should work with

```
location / {
    try_files $uri nodejs;
}
```

and

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ $1/ break;
    proxy_pass http://php:80;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. So is there a way to create aliases for the services?

Comment: I don't see why you need aliases for services. The names of services you put into your `docker-compose.yml` serve as aliases. You will find them in `/etc/hosts` in each individual container. In worst case, you could go with `container_name`.

Comment: @AlexKarshin  You could need aliases when using different images that expect a service to have different names (i.e. mysql vs db)